# XHPROF/XHGUI with apacheBench

Tags: apachebench, xhprof

I'm currently setting up a benchmark for different frameworks.

I succesfully installed and configured XHProf and XHGui (from https://github.com/perftools/xhgui.git). So far everything is going well and I can execute my benchmarks through the webbrowser without any problems.

However, I want to automize my tests using the Apache bench tool. But when I use the following apache bench command xhgui won't store anything to the database and therfore not giving me any results at all:

```
ab -n 10000 -c 200 http://IP_OF_TEST_APPLICATION/
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I could get that to work or if it should work already and I'm just doing something terribly wrong with one of the tools?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had a mistake in my url which lead to not executing the profiler when running the ab command.